# How to align hand-held 5 shot bracketing with Photoshop and overwrite each file so that metadata stays correct?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

Idea is to align with Photoshop and combine to HDR with Photomatix.

Comment: Hi Tõnu, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Please, explain a bit more, your question is very unclear to me. Also, could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Not sure why people are voting to close, it makes perfect sense to me I just don't know the answer :\ I never really pay attention to Metadata

Comment: This is an appropriate asked question. You might want to also ask this question photo.stackexchange.com as they may have more knowledge on photo metadata. You're able to edit metadata in Photoshop. Go to File > File Info. You can manually add metadata to the HDR Panorama. I am not sure how you would overwrite each file. Have you tried photomerge and see if the final image has any metadata attached to it?

Comment: I load all pictures to layers in photoshop... Auto Align them and export using a script called export layers to files... I then import them to photomatix. Theres my problem... Photomatix asks me to provide fstop.

Comment: @Tõnu - why are you using Photoshop at that point in your workflow? Do you feel the Photomatix auto-alignment is inferior in some way?